# Como implementar uma quebra de linha no JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Estou programando em JavaScript dentro do HTML e queria saber aonde eu adicionaria a quebra de linha `br` nessa linha?

```
document.write('Seu nome em maiúsculo é ' + nome.toUpperCase())
```

Para eu conseguir depois que ter o nome da pessoa em maiúsculo exibido, fazer outro `document.write`, mas na linha de baixo.

Comment: document.write('Seu nome em maiúsculo é ' + nome.toUpperCase() + '<br>') não funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar:

**document.write('Seu nome em maiúsculo é *\n*' + nome.toUpperCase())**

É possível substituir o **\n** pelo **br** (entre tags).